Skip Deleterows_v1 event errors MariaDB on replication slave
So i'm running an custom HA setup for CyberPanel.
Now their is an issue that stops the replication: skip Could not execute Deleterows_v1 event error mariadb
I wanna skip these errors. How can i do that?
Some info:

MariaDB 10.3.39
Ubuntu server 22.04

Error message:

Could not execute Deleterows_v1 event on table cyberpanel.databases_globaluserdb; Can't find record in 'databases_globaluserdb', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 300927

